# QML delete the object which created from C++

Tags: c++, qml

I created `TreeView` and get the `model` data from the C++ side by calling a function, which return a `QStandardItemModel` pointer to QML.

Here is the function:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QStandardItemModel* getImgs(){
    QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[Qt::DisplayRole] = "name_role";
    model->setItemRoleNames(roles);
    foreach (QString k, mImgs.keys()) {
        QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem();
        item->setText(k);
        foreach (QString pic, mImgs.value(k)) {
            QStandardItem* sub = new QStandardItem();
            sub->setText(pic);
            item->appendRow(sub);
        }
        model->appendRow(item);
    }
    return model;
}
```

- Q1:
  Is there way let QML GC delete the `QStandardItemModel` object and the children.
- Q2:
  Could `QStandardItemModel clear()` free the children memory space?
- Q3:
  About using `QModelIndex currentIndex` property. eg. When index changed, How to output which row is selected and the depth?

Comment: Q1. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#ObjectOwnership-enum. How do you get the object from QML ?

Comment: Q2. `clear` will free the memory. But you must be be cautious about ownership.

Comment: Q3. Look at the api.